# Node.js - Writing an image to a USB/SD on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows

So I've written a program in Electron that will download the latest version of our image and then write it to the selected device.

I've got this working fine for Linux and OSX as I'm able to call a sub process and just run the dd command directly.

My issues come when trying to make this work on Windows, I've not been able to find a node package that does dd or something similar, and natively writing it for Windows doesn't want to work due to the chaining of commands etc.

Does anyone have any suggestions? My next idea would be to write a .bat script that is called by the sub process and try to do it that way. However if there is a platform universal approach with node that would be ideal! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't start rolling my own approach for this using Node.

[Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) is the current go-to app on Windows for burning images to various media. It has [limited command line support](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/issues/111) – the author says you should try `rufus -h` to see what's possible.

There's also [Etcher CLI](https://etcher.io/cli/), which is "experimental, proceed with caution and report issues". (Also, the Etcher GUI is actually an Electron app, so you might want to peek into what it's doing. https://github.com/resin-io/etcher)

Hope these help.

Comment: Thanks, I've looked in to Etcher and was possibly toying with the idea of packaging the CLI version along with this. The reason that I've got to create my own is due to altering the data of the image file based on user specifications. Otherwise I would have simply gone with Rufus :(